# Problem installing Dropbox on Ubuntu 12.04 (Crouton)

Tags: 12.04, xfce, dropbox, chromebook

I'm using 12.04 with Xfce on a Chromebook using crouton. The package downloads and says it needs to install proprietary software. It seems to finish and then just does nothing. It also does nothing when I try and run Dropbox again. I have just successfully installed on another machine (14.04, Xfce, non-Chromebook) where after installation it shows a GUI window asking me to log-in, which is what I'd expect.

Also if I try running `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` a process is started and the terminal remains blank (no errors).

I've also tried a number of workaround methods from similar posts, including downloading from the repo rather than the Dropbox site.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this following the steps [here](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Dropbox)

> Use apt-get if you can:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
> ```
>
> If not, this is a work in progress to help compile dropbox by source. Note the missing packages may differ for your distribution. This is for the default XFCE.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libnautilus-extension-dev python-gtk2 python-docutils
> ```
>
> Download the source and follow instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install2
>
> ```
> ./configure; make
> sudo make install
> ./dropbox start -i
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in the forum.  You probably received a downvote because you provided what the reviewers/moderators consider to be a "link-only answer".  You can certainly provide a helpful link but it is also protocol to include the basic information to actually resolve the issue and so provide a truly useful "answer".

Comment: You can mark your answer as the accepted solution by clicking the checkmark icon on the left.